# How to turn off scene transition animations

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scene

How to turn off scene transition animations?
I would like to disable the animation ONLY for the RestartGame command. so that the animation works for other commands.
Is there any script for such a thing?
this is my animation script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator transition;
    public float transitionTime = 1f;
    
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
    }

    public AudioClip impact;
    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(impact, transform.position);
    }
}
```

and this is my RestartGame command which is in another script:

```cs
public void RestartGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
}
```

Comment: What animation are you referring to?  RestartGame() doesn't look like it uses any sort of animation, all it does is call LoadScene.  Have you hooked into SceneManager events somewhere else?  It is unclear how these scene animations work, since your RestartGame does not use the LevelLoader code presented above.

Answer (score 0):

In your actualy code, the RestartGame method don't use de animation, but if you have an animation on your scene when this starts, you can save a PlayerPref variable inside the RestartGame method before load the scene, and then check the variable before the animation.

For example:

```
public void RestartGame()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isRestarting",1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
}
```

then in the start of the new scene

```
void Start ()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isRestarting",0)!=1)
    {
      //Do the animation
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another option to IEnumerator that controls the animation.

```cs
IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelInde, bool hasAnimation = true)
{
    if (hasAnimation)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(impact, transform.position);
}
```

Now set it to true when restart and false to other cases. On LoadNextLevel:

```cs
StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, false));
```